# How to install a package from source on Windows?

Tags: r, installation, package

I try to install R-Forge's CHAID package on windows using

```
install.packages("CHAID", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

But I get the error message

```
package ‘CHAID’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
Warning message: package ‘CHAID’ is not available (for R version 3.1.0)
```

Any advice on workarounds? Thanks.

Comment: You need to build from source.  If you get this message, you are probably using Windows. So, install RTools (http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and install the package from source.

Comment: I have RTools installed already. What is the exact command I would have to use? Thanks!

Comment: Try `install.packages(..., type="source")`

Comment: Apologies. I did not have RTools after all. How can I install it? `install.packages("RTools")` does not work

Comment: See http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/